# Improve readability of a short snippet while keeping StyleCop happy

Tags: c#, readability, stylecop

The code below looked ok to me when I wrote it, but when I came back to it again, it was pretty hard to grasp what is going on. There used to be parenthesis around `value == ...`, but I had to remove them after StyleCop became mandatory (I cannot really control this). So, how can I improve this section of code? I was thinking: `x = value == y ? true : false;`, but that probably is even more confusing, plus silly, although compiler will optimize that.

```
set
{
    Debug.Assert(value == ConfigType.DATABASE || value == ConfigType.FILE,
        "Configuration type must be either 'File-based' or 'Database-based'; it was: "
        + value.ToString());

    // HG TODO: The following is concise but confusing.
    this.fileBasedRadioButton.Checked = value == ConfigType.FILE;
    this.databaseBasedRadioButton.Checked = value == ConfigType.DATABASE;
}
```

Comment: Sit down with your coworkers and explain why the stylecop settings need to get changed?

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but I've never worked for a corporation, and I don't know what StyleCop is. Is it a nefarious device to arrest good style? I think it's stylistically preferable to put parens around every logical expression.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler, there is such thing as too many parens. For a very large .Net project StyleCop, FxCop, and Re#er (I do not have yet) are very valuable tools. You can point them at a not readable project, and they will help to clean it up quite a bit. Some rules make sense more than others, but then again, it is hard to reach consensus on which rules should be excluded - everyone has a diff gripe with it. So, we leave StyleCop in, and deal with things we hate, for it is right 95% of the time. It slows dev down a bit, but helps to prevent bad code (partic. FxCop). We are ok coders but tools help.

Comment: There's no override for cases like this?

Comment: @Rafe Kettler - you can disable a particular rule; you can also disable all or some rules on a particular file(s) - say generated ones. However, a large organization that can apply a lot of torque also loses a good deal of flexibility, even agility. It is like a "Deez" ship from WaterWorld movie :) Basically, too much democracy would bring progress to a stall. Sometimes it is best to agree on the lowest common denom. The benefit of StyleCop is that many rules have been thought through, so that you do not have to repeat the work. You can hate parts of it, but can you do a better job from scrat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool isFile = value == ConfigType.FILE;
bool isDatabase = value == ConfigType.DATABASE; // or isDatabase = !isFile

Debug.Assert(isFile || isDatabase, 
"Configuration type must be either 'File-based' or 'Database-based'; it was: " 
+ value.ToString()); 

this.fileBasedRadioButton.Checked = isFile;
this.databaseBasedRadioButton.Checked = isDatabase;
```

This makes it a little more readable (explicitly declaring the bool), you know it has to be true or false.

And this way, if you need to (maybe in the future) change settings based on file/database in the same method, you already have the bool handy, instead of checking each time

Comment: Doesn't improve it much IMHO The crux of the problem is that the `= value == ...` semantic is weird at first glance.

Comment: Right, but it can be smoothed with two lines of comments perhaps. The optimizing compiler will make it fast, I am sure.

Comment: @Hamish, if you read 1 byte from a file or do 1 SQL query, the performance of this code is irrelevant, optimizing compiler or no. Just a (irrelevant) comment.

Comment: @Byron - ok, but this would be helpful if there was no IO involved.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the `?:` operator use `if..else`. Sure it is a little more verbose, but you wont spend more than a few seconds figuring it out.

A few months from now when you revisit this code you will be glad you took an extra 5 lines.

**Making code easy to maintain should be your #1 priority**.

```
if (value == ConfigType.FILE)
   this.fileBasedRadioButton.Checked = true;
else
   this.fileBasedRadioButton.Checked = false;


if (value == ConfigType.DATABASE)
   this.databaseBasedRadioButton.Checked = true;
else
   this.databaseBasedRadioButton.Checked = false;
```

Comment: But now 2 lines has gone to 8 (or 9, if you count the blank)

Comment: @PostMan so what? It can be understood by even the most junior of programmers. Any time you do something clever to save a few bytes of space, you are doing yourself or someone else a disservice. Leave that stuff for code golf. Trust me I've been bitten in the butt by this  type of stuff before. And yes, it was my code :P

Comment: So we should always expand code out to it's fullest to make it easier for juniors? I guess it's a matter of preference, as I prefer to see as much as possible without scrolling

Comment: But to be fair, my boss would agree with you :)

Comment: @Postman, It isn't so much a matter of preference but good programming practice. Junior developers always get the crappy maintenance jobs, and you don't want them to be confused since they have never seen a `?:` operator. Nor do you want to spend more than 1 second figuring out what a statement does (as the op had too). No reason to expand everything, but you want to make your and others lives easier.

Comment: I'd much rather have someone who understands what the code is doing, and who spends time reading it, to make changes that someone who doesn't spend more than a second reading it. And if juniors are never introduced to `?:`, how will they ever learn?

Comment: But we are drifting a bit of subject here :)

Comment: This is too long. I don't think jimmies will have too hard a time if they don't get coddled by unnecessary `if` statements.

Comment: I'm confused. Where is the ternary operator? The original code is just setting a boolean property to the evaluation of a simple boolean expression. Although, admittedly when I do that in my code, I wrap the expression in parenthesis for clarity. bool x = (value1 == value2);

Comment: @Rob, @PostMan Perhaps this example is too simple, but my point in general is to avoid doing things that can make your code even the slightest bit hard to understand unless there is a clear benefit. I'd have no problem with the code as it was originally, but the OP said it took him a bit figure what was going on. You want to avoid this as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Indent the second and third line of the `Debug.Assert()` method. It should then look like this:

```
Debug.Assert(value == ConfigType.DATABASE || value == ConfigType.FILE,
    "Configuration type must be either 'File-based' or 'Database-based'; it was: "
    + value.ToString());
```

I know this is really a minor stylistic alteration, but I've always found when I have to pass a lot of arguments or have some really long statement, when I carry over to a newline I should indent before the `;`.

It prevents the `Debug.Assert()` from looking like 3 lines.

As for the `value==`, I agree with the previous poster. You should make a `bool` `isDatabase` and `isFile` to prevent calling a field from `ConfigType` twice in your first arg.

Comment: Thanks for taking the question seriously. I did improve the formatting.